# How to use regular expression syntax to remove "ellipsis" from text in a given column?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am using this code but it does not remove "ellipsis":

Column Review contains 1500 rows of text

```
Df["Reviews"] = Df['Reviews'].apply(lambda x : " ".join(re.findall('[\w\.]+',x)))
```

example text would be: "dealer said it does not reimburse dealers for loaners or rentals... so why even be a dealership if they make faulty cars and you re on the line to help customers"

Comment: please [edit] your question when you want to add additional information

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208861/replace-characters-not-working-in-python or try using "\" before the ellipsis and set regex = true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try any of the below ways-

**With** [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/7)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 400)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Reviews':['dealer said it does not reimburse dealers for loaners or rentals... so why even be a dealership if they make faulty cars and you re on the line to help customers']})
df['Reviews'] = df['Reviews'].replace('\.+','.',regex=True)
print(df)
```

**With** [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/6)

```
import re
regex = r"[.]+"
test_str = "dealer said it does not reimburse dealers for loaners or rentals... so why even be a dealership if they make faulty cars and you re on the line to help customers" 
subst = "."
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
if result:
    print (result)
```

**With** [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/eM5kV8/30)

```
import re
regex = r"(\W)\1+"
test_str = "dealer said it does not reimburse dealers for loaners or rentals... so why even be a dealership if they make faulty cars and you re on the line to help customers"
subst = "\\1"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)   
if result:
    print (result)
```

Comment: interesting, let me try this

Comment: @Saud I've added a new answer with pandas, I urge you to try that

Comment: please share the answer with pandas, that would be interesting

Comment: @Saud added answer with `pandas`, have a look again

Comment: yes, pandas works, thanks

Comment: best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Series.str.replace should work for simple expressions:

```
df.Reviews.str.replace("...", "")
```

Comment: shouldn't it be regex = True ?

Comment: it is not really working for me

Comment: I think `'\...'` is the correct pattern, and @Sid29 `.str.replace` defaults to `regex=True`

Comment: the replace function doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove this specific word from each row, then you don't need to use RegEx. You can use `str.replace` as indicated here: [How to strip a specific word from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669024/how-to-strip-a-specific-word-from-a-string)

```
Df["Reviews"] = Df['Reviews'].apply(lambda x:x.replace("ellipsis",""))
```

Comment: by ellipsis i mean "..."