# Replace to remove nextline

Tags: python

For example, I have a text file:

```
bla bla "TEXT TEXT"
 ,BLA BLA TEXT
```

ANd I would like to make it

```
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
```

What should I put here, to make this happen?

```
.replace("\n ", "")
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry my fault that has not made it clear

```
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
bla bla "TEXT TEXT"
 ,BLA BLA TEXT
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
```

to

```
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
bla bla "TEXT TEXT",BLA BLA TEXT
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: this .replace("\n ", "") should work

Comment: Problem is it does not work. I'm not sure how to remove (next line + space and replace it with nothing)

Comment: `.replace("\n ", "")` works fine. Post the code you tried and describe what you observed.

Comment: Try `replace.('[\r\n]+', '')`

Comment: Strings are immutable, you need to assign the result of replace to a variable

Comment: Possible duplicate: [replace characters not working in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7208861/1324033)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Looks really promising,  but unfortunately does not work...((

Comment: @Sayse WHy this is offtopic? I clearly show what I have and what I need to get... And what I have tried.... ANy explanation?

Comment: @Bobbby - Because its stating that something doesn't work without clearly demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `re.sub` here:

```
input = """bla bla \"TEXT TEXT\"
           ,BLA BLA TEXT"""
output = re.sub(r'\n\s*', '', input)
```

This would let you remove newlines followed by any amount of following whitespace.

For your current approach, it should work, but the issue is that you need to assign the result back to another string, e.g.

```
output = input.replace("\n ", "")
```

Comment: re.sub(r'\n ,', '', input)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace("\n", "")`

You had a trailing white-space after `\n`

Commenting is hard for newcomers.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the expected output it seems the OP wants the space after `\n`.

Comment: weird, am I misreading it?
It seems the desired output is `TEXT",BLA` from what was originally `TEXT"
 ,BLA`

Comment: @bobbby : Have you given this a try?

Answer (score 0):

```
input = """ bla bla \"TEXT TEXT\" ,BLA BLA TEXT \n bla bla \"TEXT TEXT\" ,BLA BLA TEXT \n bla bla "TEXT TEXT" \n  ,BLA BLA TEXT \n bla bla \"TEXT TEXT\" ,BLA BLA TEXT """
print (input)
print ("-------------------")
print (input.replace("\n  ,", ","))
```

output:

```
 bla bla "TEXT TEXT" ,BLA BLA TEXT 
 bla bla "TEXT TEXT" ,BLA BLA TEXT 
 bla bla "TEXT TEXT" 
  ,BLA BLA TEXT 
 bla bla "TEXT TEXT" ,BLA BLA TEXT 
-------------------
 bla bla "TEXT TEXT" ,BLA BLA TEXT 
 bla bla "TEXT TEXT" ,BLA BLA TEXT 
 bla bla "TEXT TEXT" ,BLA BLA TEXT 
 bla bla "TEXT TEXT" ,BLA BLA TEXT
```

Comment: Looks logical and correct, but do not work

Comment: can you put your text that you are printing, something like : input = """ bla bla \"TEXT TEXT\" ,BLA BLA TEXT \n bla bla \"TEXT TEXT\" ,BLA BLA TEXT \n bla bla "TEXT TEXT" \n  ,BLA BLA TEXT \n bla bla \"TEXT TEXT\" ,BLA BLA TEXT """ @Bobbby

Comment: This text is coming from API, and because fo some but it prints sometimes bugged lines and I need to repalce them, but do not work at all... have no idea how to fix it.